# Movie clip repeat

Tags: node-editor

I'm using a movie clip node in the scene node settings. I'd like this to loop, but I've yet to figure out how to accomplish this. Could somebody please give me a hand?

Comment: I guess a "movie clip" node can't be looped, sadly. Depending on your needs, you could revert to use a "movie" texture, which can be set as "cyclic", maybe?

Comment: @m.ardito I've been unable to add a image/movie texture node into the scene settings at all. Perhaps this would solve the problem, but it seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, it could much depend on your needs, since "in the scene node settings" doesn't say a lot on what you're trying to do, but to use a video/movie texture in nodes you can use a setup like this in compositing nodes, for example:

[image]

I've highlighted relevant settings in the image above.

Of course you'll need to add to this simple node setup other

Comment: I didn't even know about this node! Thank you so much! :-)